# group by clause in sql oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

so i have to write this query where i need to calculate the average amount of **paid and withdraw** operation for **each** account so it must look like this :

[image]

my table --> operation (Naccount,date_operation,average,nature_operation(withdraw/paid))

i wrote this query , and the problem is that its calculating and selecting only the account which has both paid and withdraw operation leaving the ones that only has paid or withdraw.

`select x.naccount
       avg (x.amount) as paid
       avg (y.amount) as withdraw
from operation x, operation y 
where 
      x.nature_op = 'paid' 
      and
      y.nature_op = 'withdraw' 
      and
      x.naccount = y.naccount
group by x.naccount;`

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and expected data as formatted text, not as images (or links to images.)

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `case` expressions to do conditional aggregation:

```
select o.naccount,
       avg(case when o.nature_op = 'paid' then o.amount end) as paid,
       avg(case when o.nature_op = 'withdraw' then o.amount end) as withdraw
from operation o 
group by o.naccount;
```

**Edit:** To get 0 instead of null *if paid or withdraw doesn't exist*, use `coalesce()`:

```
select o.naccount,
       coalesce(avg(case when o.nature_op = 'paid' then o.amount end), 0) as paid,
       coalesce(avg(case when o.nature_op = 'withdraw' then o.amount end), 0) as withdraw
from operation o 
group by o.naccount;
```

Comment: this solution gives null if paid or withdraw doesn't exist , is there a way to turn them to 0 ?

Comment: I've added that query too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the conditional aggregation as follows:

```
SELECT
    X.NACCOUNT,
    COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN X.NATURE_OP = 'paid' THEN X.AMOUNT END) 
                / COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN X.NATURE_OP = 'paid' THEN 1 END), 1) 
    , 0) AS PAID,
    COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN X.NATURE_OP = 'withdraw' THEN X.AMOUNT END) 
                / COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN X.NATURE_OP = 'withdraw' THEN 1 END), 1)
    , 0) AS WITHDRAW
FROM OPERATION X
GROUP BY X.NACCOUNT;
```